# What is the cipher in the credits of "Under the Silver Lake"?

Tags: plot-explanation, under-the-silver-lake

*Under the Silver Lake* is a movie about paranoia, conspiracies, schizophrenia, and hallucinations in a backdrop of hedonistic LA parties. The main character solves (or has delusions of solving) ciphers in his quest to find a missing lover. Or perhaps the missing person is merely a female neighbor who doesn’t know him, and he only fantasized the relationship. In either case, several key events are open to interpretation.

I watched the credits carefully looking to see if the writer/director himself had a more concrete meaning to the film and maybe put a hint at the end. While doing so I noticed a credits scene that was all cipher.

> B EBWJE SPCFSU NJUDIFMM GJMN
>   VOEFS UIF TJMWFS MBLF

[image: cipher in movie credits]

Does any one know what the cipher says? Note the hint in the lower right of “B = A”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) where b=a. It says:

> A DAVID ROBERT MITCHELL FILM
>    UNDER THE SILVER LAKE

You can see this yourself by using a site [like this](https://cryptii.com/pipes/caesar-cipher).

Comment: It's been a while since I see a Caeser's